# Python url requests with multithreading

Tags: python, url, request

One of my requirements is to send a upload request for each video in a whole folder.

How do I change it to multi thread requests?

My idea is to import threading, the purpose is to upload to aws-s3.

```
import requests
import base64
import hashlib
import os

tools_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
project_root = os.path.dirname(tools_dir)
videos_dir = os.path.join(project_root, "output", "videos")

# Basic auth settings
basic_auth_user = "abc123"
basic_auth_password = "abc456"
auth = (basic_auth_user + ":" + basic_auth_password)

# Base64 encode and decode
auth_encode_format = auth.encode("utf-8")
auth_encode_base64 = base64.b64encode(auth_encode_format)
auth_encode_base64_format = auth_encode_base64.decode("utf-8")

str1 = "_"

for file in os.listdir(videos_dir):
    # print(file[0:10:])
    # print(file[:file.index(str1)])
    serial_number = file[:file.index(str1)]
    # print(f'{serial_number}')
    m = hashlib.md5()
    with open(os.path.join(videos_dir, file), 'rb') as f:
        for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
            m.update(chunk)
    h = m.hexdigest()
    url = "http://localhost:8000/api/awss3/upload"
    payload = {
    'fileHash': f'{h}',
    'device': {'serialNumber':f'{serial_number}'}
    }
    files = [('file', (f'{file}', open(os.path.join(videos_dir, file), 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream'))]
    headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Basic {auth_encode_base64_format}'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers = headers, data = payload, files = files)
    print("\n" + response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert loop-based code without side effects (like the code you have here) to multithreaded code is to switch to using a [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)-based approach instead. You can then use a thread or [process pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) instead of needing to manually manage threads yourself.

This is a rough approximation of your code at the moment:

```py
for file_path in big_list_of_files:
    ...
```

You could do this by pulling the logic from your loop to a function as an intermediate step:

```py
def upload_file(file_path):
    ...

for file_path in big_list_of_files:
    upload_file(file_path)
```

making it easy to switch to a map based approach. Uploading files is IO bound rather than CPU bound, so you probably want to use [`multiprocessing.dummy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.dummy), which is an implementation of the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module using threads instead of processes. `4` in this case is the number of threads to use:

```py
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def upload_file(file_path):
    ...

with Pool(4) as thread_pool:
    thread_pool.map(upload_file, big_list_of_files)
```

If you're uploading files to S3, it might be a better idea to consider using Amazon's [`boto3`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html) library instead, which should simplify your code and will automatically perform checksum validation and use multipart uploads for bigger files.

Comment: You might also want to consider using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) to work with file paths